# Pandas -> DataFrame -> rank by price

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ranking, rank

I have the DataFrame, where I am trying to add a new "rank" column to determine the price rating relative to the "name" and "country" columns by comparing prices (column 'price').
If one product's price is the same, when using the

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('name')['price'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().rank())
```

I get the following result -> column 'rank', but I need to get the one that is highlighted in the 'rank_2' and it is not accurate, because these six products have the same price and should get a rating of 1. How is it possible to get the given result as in the column -> 'rank_2'.
Help please, I will be grateful

[image]

Comment: Why canada and brazil have different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

You can use:

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values(by=['name', 'price']).groupby(['name'])[['price']].apply(lambda x: x!= x.shift()).cumsum()
```

OR

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values(by=['name', 'price']).groupby('name')['price'].apply(lambda x: x.rank(method="dense"))
```

Output in both cases:

```
     name country  price  rank
0  S00123     mal    3.5   1.0
1  S00123     fra    3.5   1.0
2  S00123     spa    3.5   1.0
3  S00123     pur    3.5   1.0
4  S00123     rom    3.5   1.0
5  S00123     slo    3.5   1.0
6  S00123     jap    7.0   2.0
7  S00123     can    8.5   3.0
8  S00123     bra    8.5   3.0
9  S00123     ind   10.0   4.0
```

Comment: Muhammad Hassan - thanks for your comment and explain, all works!

Answer (score 2):

you have to select the method of ranking in the rank function, like so :

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('name')['price'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().rank(method="dense"))
```

Comment: Sorting inside lambda won't work as it will change the index and assigning it to rank column will give `incompatible index` error